# Clearing photos space from device via USB, keeping auto backup

Tags: backup, storage, photos

I am running out of storage space on my mobile device.  I am using photos auto-backup, and would like to still be available to view my photos/videos when I want to from my device.  Can I connect via USB and delete/move files from `Internal Storage\DCIM\Camera` and be sure they will still be available from the photos app while I am online?